# use specific memory section memory to link a variable

Tags: gcc, linker, arm

I'm having trouble in setting the section attribute of gcc to define that a variable should reside in a specific memory section instead of the default.

I'm using the arm cortex m3 LPC1759. I got the link files from LPCXpresso IDE, but I don't use it, I have my own makefile. The link files are:

#### Generic link file

```
INCLUDE "./link/LPCmem.ld" /* see below */

ENTRY(ResetISR)

SECTIONS
{
    /* MAIN TEXT SECTION */    
    .text : ALIGN(4)
    {
        FILL(0xff)
        __vectors_start__ = ABSOLUTE(.) ;
        KEEP(*(.isr_vector))
        
        /* Global Section Table */
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
        __section_table_start = .;
        __data_section_table = .;
        LONG(LOADADDR(.data));
        LONG(    ADDR(.data));
        LONG(  SIZEOF(.data));
        LONG(LOADADDR(.data_RAM2));
        LONG(    ADDR(.data_RAM2));
        LONG(  SIZEOF(.data_RAM2));
        __data_section_table_end = .;
        __bss_section_table = .;
        LONG(    ADDR(.bss));
        LONG(  SIZEOF(.bss));
        LONG(    ADDR(.bss_RAM2));
        LONG(  SIZEOF(.bss_RAM2));
        __bss_section_table_end = .;
        __section_table_end = . ;
        /* End of Global Section Table */
        

        *(.after_vectors*)
    } >FLASH
    
    .text : ALIGN(4)    
    {
         *(.text*)
        *(.rodata .rodata.* .constdata .constdata.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        
    } > FLASH

    /*
     * for exception handling/unwind - some Newlib functions (in common
     * with C++ and STDC++) use this. 
     */
    .ARM.extab : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH
    __exidx_start = .;
    
    .ARM.exidx : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
    } > FLASH
    __exidx_end = .;
    
    _etext = .;
    
    /* DATA section for SRAM0 */
    .data_RAM2 : ALIGN(4)
    {
       FILL(0xff)
       *(.ramfunc.$RAM2)
       *(.ramfunc.$SRAM0)
        *(.data.$RAM2*)
        *(.data.$SRAM0*)
       . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } > SRAM0 AT>FLASH
    
    /* MAIN DATA SECTION */
    .uninit_RESERVED : ALIGN(4)
    {
        KEEP(*(.bss.$RESERVED*))
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
        _end_uninit_RESERVED = .;
    } > SRAM
    
    /* Main DATA section (SRAM) */
    .data : ALIGN(4)
    {
       FILL(0xff)
       _data = . ;
       *(vtable)
       *(.ramfunc*)
       *(.data*)
       . = ALIGN(4) ;
       _edata = . ;
    } > SRAM AT>FLASH

    /* BSS section for SRAM0 */
    .bss_RAM2 : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.bss.$RAM2*)
        *(.bss.$SRAM0*)
       . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } > SRAM0

    /* MAIN BSS SECTION */
    .bss : ALIGN(4)
    {
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4) ;
        _ebss = .;
        PROVIDE(end = .);
    } > SRAM
        
    /* NOINIT section for SRAM0 */
    .noinit_RAM2 (NOLOAD) : ALIGN(4)
    {
        *(.noinit.$RAM2*)
        *(.noinit.$SRAM0*)
       . = ALIGN(4) ;
    } > SRAM0 
    
    /* DEFAULT NOINIT SECTION */
    .noinit (NOLOAD): ALIGN(4)
    {
        _noinit = .;
        *(.noinit*) 
         . = ALIGN(4) ;
        _end_noinit = .;
    } > SRAM
        
    PROVIDE(_pvHeapStart = .);
    PROVIDE(_vStackTop = __top_SRAM - 0);
}
```

#### Memory definition file

```
/* Define each memory region */
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x0, LENGTH = 0x80000           /* 512K bytes */
  SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x8000     /* 32K bytes */
  SRAM0 (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x2007c000, LENGTH = 0x8000    /* 32K bytes */
}

/* Define a symbol for the top of each memory region */
__top_FLASH = 0x0 + 0x80000;
__top_SRAM = 0x10000000 + 0x8000;
__top_SRAM0 = 0x2007c000 + 0x8000;
```

Above is the *LPCmem.ld* file included by the previous file.

I'm forcing the freertos heap variable to be in the custom section, like this:

```
static unsigned char ucHeap[ configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE ]
        __attribute__((section(".data_RAM2")));
```

The linking of objects files are done without errors, but the variable isn't placed in the right memory position, how I could check with nm command:

```
...
10000028 d ucHeap
10002028 d uxCriticalNesting
...
```

I try to change the section to other that doesn't exists, just to check if the linker verify the names and apparently it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - You are just missing the **dollar sign**.

You are naming the section wrong.  The relevant portions of the linker file are,

```
/* DATA section for SRAM0 */
.data_RAM2 : ALIGN(4)
{
   FILL(0xff)
   *(.ramfunc.$RAM2)
   *(.ramfunc.$SRAM0)
    *(.data.$RAM2*)
    *(.data.$SRAM0*)
    /* *(.data_RAM2);   You need this, without a code change, */
    /*                  but it will still match data. */
   . = ALIGN(4) ;
} > SRAM0 AT>FLASH

/* Main DATA section (SRAM) */
.data : ALIGN(4)
{
   FILL(0xff)
   _data = . ;
   *(vtable)
   *(.ramfunc*)
   *(.data*)     /* Otherwise, this matches your section. */
   . = ALIGN(4) ;
   _edata = . ;
} > SRAM AT>FLASH
```

Currently, you have `ucHeap` in `.data_RAM2`.  The linker file used `.data.$RAM2*`, but this will not match.  The `*` is a wild card.  So the `*(.data*)` will match your code as you currently have it.  I don't know if you have an issue with,

```
 static unsigned char ucHeap[ configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE ] 
    __attribute__((section(".data_$RAM2")));
```

This seems to work with my version of gcc.  You are just missing the **dollar sign**.
See the [gnu ld documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/SECTIONS.html), specifically the [input sections](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section.html).  The form is,
 *archive*:*object file*(*input section* *...*);  where you can use the wild cards and can omit the *archive:*, if you like.  The wildcards are a limited *reg-ex* form.  You can give many input sections if you like; for example `*(.text* .rodata*)` will place the `.text` and `.rodata` from the same object together.  Where as, `*(.text*); *(.rodata*);` will keep all `.text` together from all object files and then place the `.rodata`.

Comment: Thanks, using `__attribute__((section(".data.$RAM2")))` it works fine. Now, is possible use the RAM2 without change the code: I mean, not using the __attribute__ section, the linker is able to solve this automatically?

Comment: You could put all `.data` in a particular object file in a section using the linker script.  If you want to only put particular variables in source/object/compilation unit into a section, then `attribute` is the proper way.